# Codeblocks editor does not show file tabs

Tags: tabs, codeblocks

When I open any file in Codeblocks, why can't see it in a file tabs on top of the code window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

View -> unmark "Hide editor tabs".

Alternatively, View -> Perspectives -> Code::Blocks default, to restore the default view.